# Build a RVIZ plugin with catkin_make

Tags: rviz, rviz-plugins

i want to create an RVIZ-Plugin. I used the plant_flag_tool tutorial. The first step was to create a package called plant_flag_tool (catkin_create_package plant_flag_tool roscpp rviz). Then i created the .cpp and the .h file. It also says in the tutorial that there is an package.xml and a plugin_description.xml. The package.xml should be fine. But I am not sure what i have to insert to the plugin_description.xml and to the CMakeList.txt. I am new at this, and so i dont know how to proceed from here on.

When i try to build it with catkin_make, there is an error:
Thank you for your help.

[image: catkin_make error]

[image: path in catkin ws]

[image: plugin_description.xml]

Comment: Please paste any console output as code formatted text and not as a screenshot. Screenshots are not text searchable, [amongst other things](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)....

Answer (score 1):

Check if QT is installed in your environment, and if not, install it